# Matching the whole path

Tags: clojure, compojure

What's the proper way to match the entire path?

```
(defroutes app
  (ANY "*" [*]
       {:status 200
        :headers {"Content-Type" "text/plain"}
        :body (str "path = " *)}))
```

works but it also gives me the compiler warning `WARNING: * should not be used as a route binding.`

```
(defroutes app
  (ANY "*" [path]
       {:status 200
        :headers {"Content-Type" "text/plain"}
        :body (str "path = " path)}))
```

compiles without a warning but doesn't bind `path` to the path.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like

```
(defroutes app
  (ANY [":path" :path #".*"] [path]
       {:status 200
        :headers {"Content-Type" "text/plain"}
        :body (str "path = " path)}))
```

works.